# Jmeter Html Report show more than one(first) failed assertion

Tags: java, jmeter

Does anyone know if it is possible to configure the Jmeter html report so that the html report shows not only the first failed assertions, but all?
Generated xml_log.jtl looks like this.

```
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Response Assertion [202]</name>
    <failure>true</failure>
    <error>false</error>
    <failureMessage>Test failed: code expected to equal /

received  : [2]00

comparison: [3]00

/</failureMessage>
  </assertionResult>
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Duration Assertion [5ms] request</name>
    <failure>true</failure>
    <error>false</error>
    <failureMessage>The operation lasted too long: It took 293 milliseconds, but should not have lasted longer than 5 milliseconds.</failureMessage>
  </assertionResult>
```

And generated report:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) can only be generated from [.jtl results files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) in **CSV format**

> The dashboard generator is a modular extension of JMeter. Its default behavior is to read and process samples from **CSV files** to generate HTML files containing graph views.

and the .jtl results file in CSV format stores information only about first failed assertion.

You can work it around by adding a [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to walk through all the assertion failures, combine failure messages into a single one and substitute first assertion's failure message with this combined cumulative synthetic one, example code:

```
def message = new StringBuilder()

prev.getAssertionResults().each { assertionResult ->
    message.append(assertionResult.getFailureMessage()).append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
}

if (prev.getAssertionResults().size() > 0) {
    prev.getAssertionResults().first().setFailureMessage(message.toString())
}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You read my question a little inattentively and gave me a standard answer.

Comment: 1. As you can see from my question, I have an XML JTL file. Accordingly, it has more than two failed asserts.
2. I know that csv displays only one assert.
3. Accordingly, your answer is a little wrong, since I have an XML.jtl file
4. I do everything in java. GroovyListener is not suitable for me and is not needed, since there are 2 assertions in the jtl file. This is where my question is. Why generated html doesn't show both failed asserts from jtl file.
5. If html shows only 1 assertion, then how can I combine all assertions before writing to jtl file?
Thanks!